# Deciding to the clustering algorithm for the dataset containing both categorical and numerical variables

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca

I am a newbie in machine learning and trying to make a segmentation with clustering algorithms. However, Since my dataset has both categorical variables (such as gender, marital status, preferred social media platform etc) as well as numerical variables ( average expenditure, age, income etc.), I could not decide which algorithms worth to focus on. Which one should I try: hierarchical clustering, fuzzy c means, k-medoids, or latent class to compare with k-means++? which ones would yield better results for these type of mixed datasets?

Bonus question: Should I try to do clustering without dimensionality reduction? or should I use PCA or K-PCA in any case to decrease dimensions? Also, how can I understand and interpret results without visualization if the dataset has more than 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a distance metric designed for mixed data. For example, Gower distance (Gower 1971) is a popular choice. You could then use any distance-based clustering method, e.g. hierarchical clustering, k-medoids, DBSCAN, OPTICS, spectral clustering, etc.

You can't use a clustering method that computes centroids, because the mean isn't defined for categorical values. This rules out methods like k-means, fuzzy c-means, Gaussian mixture models, hierarchical clustering with Ward linkage, etc. Beyond that constraint, having mixed data doesn't indicate which clustering method you should use. Rather, it depends on your goals, the structure of your data, and computational considerations. There are multiple threads on this site to help guide you in this choice.

Mixed data also means you can't use PCA, which isn't defined for categorical variables. But, you could use multidimensional scaling (MDS) or kernel PCA in conjunction with a distance metric or kernel function that handles mixed data. This could be used simply for visualization, or for preprocessing or dimensionality reduction prior to clustering. Whether to perform dimensionality reduction before clustering is, again, problem dependent. Note that MDS and kPCA embed the data into a real vector space. So, if you take this approach, you'd be clustering transformed, continuous values rather than mixed data, and the above restrictions on the clustering method would no longer apply.

References:

Gower (1971). A general coefficient of similarity and some of its properties.

Comment: Can I use kPCA if I encode my categorical data into numerical values such as OneHotEncoder transformation?

Comment: Sure, you can use kPCA with any type of data your kernel function can handle. The real question for any visualization or clustering approach is whether it will provide helpful insights into the data--i.e. can you interpret what the results mean?

Comment: That is correct, I have been searching for a decent way to interpret how the features affect every principal component. I found that  heatmap might help me to understand which features affect in which direction so I will try to use it. Also, thank you for the answer!

Comment: I would like to ask two more things regarding this question:

-Can I also use Gower Distance to execute k-means algorithm?

-Can I apply K-pca to the results of Gower Distance matrix to visualize later?

Comment: My answer already addresses your question about k-means. kPCA requires a kernel function. It might be possible to construct one based on Gower distance, but it would be better to start with MDS for visualization, which can operate directly on Gower distance.